# How do you pull data from external files, and then use it? i.e. Visit The 5 URLs in url.txt

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I want to visit every URL listed on a text file.

I have:

```
require 'mechanize'

File.open('sources.txt').each_line { |url|
  agent = Mechanize.new
  puts "Visiting #{url}"
  mypage = agent.get("#{url}")
  current_url = mypage.uri.to_s
  puts "The final URL is #{current_url}"
}
```

This code runs through the URLs in `sources.txt`, tells you it's doing so, then tells you the URL once it reaches the page. i.e. if `www.foo.com` is in the `source.txt`, but `www.foo.com` resolves to just `foo.com` (no WWW), it will tell you so.

How can I save EACH resolved/final/current URL into a single, line separated text file?

Comment: First, take Mechanize.new outside of the loop. Second, it sounds like you're just looking for someone to do your work for you. Do a google search on how to write to a file in ruby before posting questions like this please.

Comment: I have no purpose to do that. I want to learn Ruby myself, this is not homework. I'm on hour 4 of Mechanize now, and I've read through this - http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/io/. I can only get the file to be overwritten each time with only 1 URL. I think \n is the answer, but I can't include it without errors.

Comment: If you have some code where you attempt to write to a file you should post it. The code you posted only reads from a file.

Comment: Why do you have mypage = agent.get("#{url}")? Shouldn't mypage = agent.get(url) work fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append to a file, you use 'a' flag instead of 'w'. Flags are here http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html

```
50.times do |n|
  File.open 'destinations.txt', 'a' do |file|
    file.write "line #{n}\n"
  end
end
```

Update (some refactoring to your code):

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new

output = File.open 'output.txt', 'a'
File.open('sources.txt').each_line do |url|
  puts "Visiting #{url}"
  mypage = agent.get("#{url}")
  @current_url = mypage.uri.to_s
  puts "The final URL is #{@current_url}"
  output.puts @current_url
end
output.close
```

This way you will open each file once.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new

File.open('sources.txt').each_line do |url|
  puts "Visiting #{url}"
  mypage = agent.get("#{url}")
  @current_url = mypage.uri.to_s
  puts "The final URL is #{@current_url}"
File.open('output.txt', 'a') do |output| 
output.puts @current_url
end
 end
```

Sorry about the formatting, I'm still awkward about where to put in indentations.

Comment: Updated my answer to improve your code. You should not open output file unnecessary so many times.